# Clicking button with Selenium Python tried many ways with xpath and css selector without success

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to click this [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pu7P.jpg) highlighted in yellow with Selenium in Python

From this webpage:
https://www.femina.fr/article/jeu-concours-spartoo-decembre-2020

I've passed both the cookies and allow/block notifications popups.

I'm trying in plain windows(?), I mean I'm not trying this in *headless* mode.

Tried with Chrome and Firefox webdriver: same results.

I've tried all the following without success:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Jouer et s'inscrire !']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Etape suivante']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'Jouer et s'inscrire !')]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jouerBtn']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/input[3]").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=submit]").click()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding time sleep and also to get xpath right click button > inspect element > control click input > copy full xpath

Comment: It's the 5th I've tried if you look at my code: driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/input[3]").click()

Comment: Have you first clicked past the screen requesting that you accept cookies? And it would help if you 1. posted Minimal Reproducible Code 2. the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @Booboo yes, I passed both the cookies and the allow/block notifications popups. I don't have much code yet because I won't code anything if I can't pass this button :) The error is pretty simple and the same for every method I tried: *no such element: Unable to locate element*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button you are looking for is within an `<iframe>`, which you have to first switch to before you can do your `find_element_by_xpath`:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('qualifio-0136862F-D302-43A1-A613-F291B4D70337')
```

The simplest way to then find the button is:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('jouerBtn')
```

Answer (score 1):

The element <kbd>Jouer et s'inscrire !</kbd> is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.femina.fr/article/jeu-concours-spartoo-decembre-2020')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#didomi-notice-agree-button>span"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='qualifio']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#jouerBtn"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.femina.fr/article/jeu-concours-spartoo-decembre-2020')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'accepte')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'qualifio')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='jouerBtn']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: femina_france]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score -1):

Following XPaths are correct

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jouerBtn']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/input[3]").click()
```

Following XPaths/CSS are not correct

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Jouer et s'inscrire !']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Etape suivante']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button(contains(., 'Jouer et s'inscrire!')]").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=submit]").click()
```

The element (button) is not in the visible area of the screen. Hence element should be brought into the visible area before clicking.

Corrections to the location syntax

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=\"Jouer et s'inscrire !\"]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and @value=\"Jouer et s'inscrire !\"]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@value, 'Jouer et s')]").click() 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type='button']").click()
```